# How to make iframe fit ionic modal

Tags: css, iframe, ionic-framework

I'm facing a tiny problem to show an iframe in ionic modal, I want the iframe to be full width and height depending on the ionic app window.

Here is my modal code :

```html
<ion-modal-view>
  <div class="bar bar-header" style="border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;position:relative">
    <div class="h1 title" style="display:flex;flex-direction:column;line-height:initial;justify-content:center;padding:0 32px">
      {{team.name}}
    </div>
    <button class="button button-clear button-positive" ng-click="modal.hide()">Fermer</button>
  </div>

  <io-content>
    <iframe src="http://www.wikipedia.fr" style="width: 100%; height: 100%!important"></iframe>
  </io-content>
</ion-modal-view>
```

[PLUNKER PERVIEW](http://plnkr.co/edit/DNT9TTpS0HdaNShkZjSW?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

To make a responsive video, try this:

Create a container div around the iframe code and give it a class eg:

```
<div class="video-container"><iframe.......></iframe></div>
```

Add in the CSS:

```
.video-container {
    position:relative;
    padding-bottom:56.25%;
    padding-top:30px;
    height:0;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.video-container iframe, .video-container object, .video-container embed {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

Font: https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/videodrome/youtube/